# How do I tell google sheets to only make a calculation after a certain time period?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Context**

So I am currently building a database of data for financial assets to conduct some machine learning from to build trading signals. I am trying to calculate the geometric mean but over a given period (monthly). I want to tell google sheets to only calculate the geometric mean after every month. I tried using this formula to no avail:

```
=IF(last date of the month - first date of month = total days in a month, 
GEOMEAN(filter(abs(range),abs(range)>0)),""))
```

** There were values in the last date of the month - first date of month = total days in a month **

It ended up doing it for every day for the 10 year data set.

** Update

This is the data:

```
 Date     Close Cleaned Data  Returns   Gross returns   Geometric average returns
13/11/2015  280   -0.0267      0             1  
16/11/2015  280   -0.0267      0             1  
17/11/2015  280   -0.0267      0             1  

...

23/12/2016  296.4   0.0236  -0.1561348935    0.8438651065
28/12/2016  295.2   0.0199  -0.0770931339    0.9229068661
29/12/2016  294.7   0.0183   0.03341318035   1.03341318
30/12/2016  294.9   0.0190   0.3718276303    1.37182763
```

**Problem** (UPDATE)

How do I create a function to let google sheet do calculations only for the last day of every month for a given time series data? Say within this time period, (1 year) I want to calculate the geometric mean for each month in this period and for new data I might want to add later in the future.

Comment: Perhap a timebased trigger.https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newTrigger(String)

Comment: Thanks for the response. This could work though I think this solves half the problem (for future data). I have updated the question. Would appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: You could create the required triggers programmatically. For the appropriate times that you want the function to run.   Look at the link I gave you and learn about the time based trigger builder.

Comment: As far as I understand given a certain data that might change at any time you mean to update the geometric mean for each month every time your sheet's been updated?

Comment: Correct. So every day I will input the last day price (or call it from google). Then at the end of the month, in the geometric mean column, I want the calculation to execute.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will have to set a trigger event. This is found within the script editor under the edit tab, second to last option.
[Image of where to find the trigger manager: It's in spanish, but it will be found in the same place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k53et.png)

Once there, click on add trigger, which will be found on the bottom right corner. The first option will ask you which function do you want to run from the bound script. Then select the source of the event and select according to time (My platform is in spanish so I'm trasnlating it you might have it written differently). Then it will prompt you: if you want it to be at an exact date and time, every minute, every hour, day, week and month. Select month and select the day of the month you want the trigger to happen in the next prompt and select the time for the last prompt, then click save.

Finding the last day of a month:

```
function lastdayOfMonths() {
  let html='';
  let td=new Date();
  for(var i=0;i<12;i++) {
    let dt=new Date(td.getFullYear(),td.getMonth()+i+1,0);
    let dts=Utilities.formatDate(dt, Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"E MMM dd,yyyy");
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<br />%s',dts);
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "Last Days of Months for next year");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. This is great and solves part of the problem. Though I already have data for years and want to create a formula to calculate for the existing data and for future data that will be inputted. Any suggestions?

Comment: I provided a method for calculating the last days of the month for the next year.

Comment: Thanks for adding to the solution Cooper, I appreciate it!

Comment: Quick question Cooper, so what I figured from your code is that the calendar doesn't work like an array, it starts at 1, so why not se i=1? Also why does var dt end with a 0? I think im just not understanding what dt is doing

Comment: Thanks a lot Cooper, I will have a go at this tonight.

Comment: Thanks also Google Script Automator!